# Cannot convert TCL serial com to C#

Tags: c#, serial-port, tcl

I'm trying to convert TCL code, used to communicate with a serial port to a "robot", to C#. But for some reason my commands are not getting responses.

This is the serial com init in TCL:

```
proc openUart {} {
    set robot::fd_ [open COM${robot::port_num}: w+]
    fconfigure $robot::fd_ -mode 9600,e,7,1
    fconfigure $robot::fd_ -blocking 0
    fconfigure $robot::fd_ -buffering none
    fileevent $robot::fd_ readable ""
}
```

A "command" is sent like this:

```
proc SendCmd {command} {
        set commandlen [string length $command]
        for {set i 0} {$i < $commandlen} {incr i} { 
            set letter [string index $command $i]
            after 10
            puts -nonewline $robot::fd_ $letter
        }
        after [expr 2 * 10] 
        puts -nonewline $robot::fd_ "\n"
        flush $robot::fd_
}
```

This is how I translated this to C#. Opening the port:

```
private void Initialize(string com)
{
    _comPort = new SerialPort(com,9600,Parity.Even,7,StopBits.One)
    {
        Encoding = Encoding.ASCII,
        NewLine = "\n"
    };
    _comPort.Open();
}
```

And sending a command:

```
private string SendCommand(Commands cmd)
{
    string commandToWrite = Command(cmd);
    for (int i = 0; i < CommandLen; i++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10);
        _comPort.Write(commandToWrite.ToCharArray(), i, 1);
    }
    Thread.Sleep(10 * 2);
    _comPort.Write("\n");
    _comPort.BaseStream.Flush();
}
```

I connected my PC to the robot with a serial to USB cable and ran both TCL and C# programs -
The TCL script turns on a LED on the robot.
My C# code doesn't turn the LED on, meaning the robot did not recognize the command.

I'm using the same com port, so I believe the problem is one of these:

1. I did not initialize the com port correctly in C#. How do you set the blocking and buffering?
2. Could there be an encoding issue in C#? isn't ASCII the default encoding in TCL?
3. Could there be a timing difference in how I'm sending the command letter-by-letter between the two languages?

Comment: sysinternals portmon is a good way to see what's travelling over the wire

Comment: Blocking is probably timeouts. Try setting `WriteTimeout` and calling `DiscardOutBuffer()`. Other things to note: 1) `Flush()`, why? 2) `"\n"` is it same in [tag:c#] and [tag:tcl] ? 3) I don't think what `10ms` delays are critical, you could simply try to send thing as a whole: `_comPort.Write(commandToWrite + "\n");` 4) You sure, what `Command(cmd)` produces correct result, there is no code to check.

Comment: If you don't set the Handshake property (you should) then you must turn on the handshake signals yourself.  Set the DtrEnable and RtsEnable properties to *true*.

Comment: Dropping the 10ms delay causes the TCL script to not work. It seems the robot is sensitive to this, not sure why. Increasing the delay to 100ms made no change though.

Comment: I also tried to run portmon, but it won't run on my Win7 64b machine

Comment: Command(cmd) returns a string that represents the command, i verified it manually. An example for a command: ":010508010000F1" which is "OFF".

Comment: @Sinatr It's _not_ timeouts. It switches Tcl to using asynchronous I/O so that all calls return immediately; the queue of characters to write to the serial line is managed between the OS and Tcl so as to keep the code live. Doing the same thing in C# _might_ require using an extra thread; the code to make this work inside the Tcl implementation is pretty deeply gnarly…

Comment: I would loop back the serial cable to the machine sending it and open the com port that the 'robot' uses.  Open some terminal emulator program and send the data with the tcl script and the C# program and just make sure they look the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved!

I finally looped back the cable into my PC using another serial cable and 2 blue wires, crossing the RX\TX (thanks don_q for the idea!).
Using a simple serial monitor, "UART Terminal", I sniffed the commands, and to my surprise the TCL script was adding a '\r' before the '\n'!

So in fact the robot was expecting this command format -

```
:010508010000F1\r\n
```

I changed the NewLine property in C# to be "\r\n", and now I finish a command by using -

```
_comPort.WriteLine("");
```

And now everything works.